# Animate CC, creating a code for collectables

Tags: actionscript, action, cc, animate-cc

I haven't coded since Macromedia, and god things have changed. I'm at a steep learning curve and trying to get back into it.

Im making a little flash game where the player collects tacos and the score goes up.

No code online that I have found for making collectable money works on Animate CC for me. I am unsure why that is. The script runs fine, debug detects nothing. But the code doesn't do anything.

I have tried this:

```
if(player.hitTestObject(taco1))
{
    if(back.contains(taco1))
        removeChild(taco1);

    score += 10;
    points.text = String(score);
}
```

which either doesnt collect the taco, or the taco follows the player (if I put it on the main scene.}

I've also tried just plugging in my instances in a code provided on AS3 game tutorials. It can be seen here, unaltered.

```
    if(keyCollected == false){ // if we still haven't collected the key
if(player.hitTestObject(back.doorKey)){ // and if the player collides 
with the key
back.doorKey.visible = false; // hide the key from view
keyCollected = true; // set our Boolean to true
}
}
```

none of this works  either.

Sorry new to forum, and haven't coded in ten years. But any points in the right direction would be so helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should wrap the hitTestObject inside a function and run it on an ENTER_FRAME event or on a TimerEvent.
If no ENTER_FRAME or timer is present your code will run only once, therefore you see no effect.

From your code I can tell that you have a reference to the **taco1** object and that object belongs to the **back** object.

```
if(back.contains(taco1))
    removeChild(taco1);
```

In the code above there is a problem. You should have:

```
if(back.contains(taco1))
    back.removeChild(taco1);
```

Other than that, the code block should work fine. For example using the ENTER_FRAME event your code will look as the code bellow:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collectTaco);

function collectTaco(evt:Event):void {
    if(taco1 != null && player.hitTestObject(taco1)) {
        if(back.contains(taco1)) {
            back.removeChild(taco1);
            taco1 = null;
        }
        score += 10;
        points.text = String(score);
    }
}
```

Note that there is an assumption that the **taco1** object always holds a reference to a taco that you want to hit test with. That's why I nullify the **taco1** after removing it from the **back**. After the taco was collected the if statement will evaluate to false, so won't try to collect it again. I think you'll create more tacos while the game goes on, and you must set a reference of the new taco to **taco1**.

If you have more tacos on the stage you should traverse all tacos (either store them in a Vector or just go through all children of the **back** parent, and maybe test them for being a Taco) and do the hit test for all of them.

Comment: This seems to run fine, but it alternates between doing nothing, or telling me "collecttaco" doesn't exist. Does it need a var?

Comment: Then you might have the code snippet only on some frames. It should have a global scope on the timeline (as it seems your game is structured on the timeline). Can you confirm that? If not, can you describe the architecture?